# Wait the end of HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to use the `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream` method. In my method I'm getting some `Json`. I need to wait the end of this method `(HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream)` to analyse my Json.

Here is my code :

```
private string API_Query(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest requete = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    requete.Method = "POST";
    requete.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    requete.BeginGetRequestStream(DebutReponse, requete);//wait the end of this method
    //analyse the json here
    return null;
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to wait the end the method. I tried different things like Task and Thread but I'm not sure how to do it correctly.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does it matter to you if the request is executed asynchronously? Because that's what it's doing with `BeginGetRequestStream`.

Comment: Yes I prefer, like that the app does not freeze. But if you have a solution with a asynchronously execution, I could use the thread after to make it asynchronously.

Comment: *synchronously I meant

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that I don't know how to wait the end the method.

There are many approaches to doing that. As it looks to me you want to invoke the request synchronously, i'd suggest simply calling `GetResponseStream`:

```
private string ApiQuery(string url)
{
   HttpWebRequest requete = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
   requete.Method = "POST";
   requete.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

   using (var requestStream = requete.GetRequestStream())
   {
      // Write to request stream
   }

   using (var responseStream = requete.GetResponse())
   {
      // Read the respone stream, parsing out your JSON.
   }
}
```

**Edit:**

As you mentioned in the comments, this is a Silverlight project. That means you don't have the synchronous version of `HttpWebRequest`. Instead, you can use `WebClient`:

```
var webClient = new WebClient()
webClient.OpenReadCompleted += OnUploadCompleted;
webClient.OpenReadAsync(url, data);

private void OnUploadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
         // Error, do something useful
         return;
    }
    using (var responseStream = e.Result)
    {
           byte[] data = (byte[]) e.UserState;
          // Read response from stream.
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I just try but I don't find the method requete.GetRequestStream(). I just have requete.BeginGetRequestStream(), is it the same ?

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm doing a Silverlight app, I don't know, or if my project is break lol.